# mysql - using reserved names as column name

Tags: mysql, reserved-words

I am trying to run this query but doesn't run

```
SELECT ng.parent_id, ng.tab, ng.post_id, ng.ORDER, ng.cluster_key, pd.id, pd.slug, pd.link_text, pd.parent
FROM `ecom_navigation` AS ng, `ecom_page_data` AS pd
WHERE ng.cluster_key = 'primary'
AND ng.tab = '0'
AND ng.parent_id = '1'pd.id = ng.post_id
ORDER BY ng.order
```

and getting error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'pd.id = ng.post_id ORDER BY ng.order' at line 1

i've tried `ng.order` and `ng`.`order` but still cant seem to get it to run.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just missing an `and`:

```
AND ng.parent_id = '1'pd.id = ng.post_id
```

should probably be:

```
AND ng.parent_id = '1'
AND pd.id = ng.post_id
```

Or better, put the join condition in the join (and don't quote your numbers unless they really are strings):

```
SELECT ng.parent_id, ng.tab, ng.post_id, ng.ORDER, ng.cluster_key, pd.id, pd.slug, pd.link_text, pd.parent
FROM `ecom_navigation` AS ng join `ecom_page_data` AS pd on ng.post_id = pd.id
WHERE ng.cluster_key = 'primary'
AND ng.tab = 0        -- Leave the quotes on if tab is a string
AND ng.parent_id = 1  -- Leave the quotes on if parent_id is a string
ORDER BY ng.order
```

Comment: as if I did not see that!! Cheers

Comment: @Phil: Come on, how many times has it been something that couldn't possibly be wrong? More than once no doubt :)

Answer (score 1):

try

`ng`.`order`

if i could get backticks to show in this editor, then they would be there, but it seems to remove them

backticks are used to escape reserved words and spaces in column names etc

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to (you have a `'` misplaced)

```
SELECT ng.parent_id, ng.tab, ng.post_id, ng.ORDER, ng.cluster_key, pd.id, pd.slug, pd.link_text, pd.parent
FROM `ecom_navigation` AS ng, `ecom_page_data` AS pd
WHERE ng.cluster_key = 'primary'
AND ng.tab = '0'
AND ng.parent_id =  '1' AND pd.id = ng.post_id
ORDER BY ng.order
```

OR

```
SELECT ng.parent_id, ng.tab, ng.post_id, ng.ORDER, ng.cluster_key, pd.id, pd.slug, pd.link_text, pd.parent
FROM `ecom_navigation` AS ng, `ecom_page_data` AS pd
WHERE ng.cluster_key = 'primary'
AND ng.tab = '0'
AND ng.parent_id =  1 AND pd.id = ng.post_id
ORDER BY ng.order
```